# MEDIAN IF S using groupby of Python Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, group-by, median

I am trying to run an Median IF NOT EQUAL to a column reference. I can group by and run a median. However, I couldn't able to run a Median group by not equal to referring to a value/character in columns.

```
import pandas as pd

# intialise data of lists. 
data={'id':[ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],
'var1':['var1','var1','var1','var1','var1','var1','var1','var1','var1','var1','var2','var2','var2','var2','var2'],
'var2':[ 'A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C','A','A','A','B','B','C'],
'var3':[ 'A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A'],
'values':[ 10,870,1731,80,110,3848,3590,344,30,60,60,190,440,780,1460]}

#Create DataFrame
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

Excel Formula:- 
=MEDIAN(IF($B:$B=H2,IF($C:$C<>$I2,$E:$E)))
Column reference:
B - var1 (input), H - grouped var1 (below output var1), C - var2(Input), I - (below output var2), E - values in input file.

Desired Output - 

var1,var2,median
var1,A,227
var1,B,344
var1,C,110
var2,A,780
var2,B,190
var2,C,315
```

I am trying to write Median IF S. Provided above the formula used in Excel.

Comment: Explain your logic in words without showing some excel formula which doesn't make any sense since we don't know which column is what.

Comment: Did you try, instead of `=MEDIAN(IF($B:$B=H2,IF($C:$C<>$I2,$E:$E)))`  ...  `=MEDIAN(IF(AND($B:$B=H2,$C:$C<>$I2),$E:$E))` ??? That double conditional will not work as expected.

Comment: Can you explain how do you get 227 for `var1, A` without showing the excel formula.

Comment: I am trying to get the median of all values against var 1 in var 1 column and NOT A in var 2 column (i.e., B and C) against 1 row in output i.e. var1,A,227.

Comment: Median of that values in groupby of [rows with value of 'var1' and rows with values NOT that in 'var2'].      That is the reason i am using <> in excel formula which says NOT EQUAL TO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT - Completely rewrote this answer.

I think you want this, given your *data* dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

res = {'input1': [], 'input2': [], 'results': []}

for i1, i2 in zip(set(data['var1']), set(data['var2'])):
    temp = df[(df['var1'] == i1) & (df['var2'] == i2)]
    row_median = temp['values'].median()
    res['input1'].append(i1)
    res['input2'].append(i2)
    res['results'].append(row_median)

print(pd.DataFrame(res))
```

Comment: Something like, ` df.groupby(['var1',(df[df['var2'] != df[var2]])).values.median() `